# Server returned error: "No route to host"

Tags: email, gmail, pop3, mail-server

```
    An unknown error occurred.
Server returned error: "No route to host"
```

Anyone who can solve this? i'm using gmail to fetch the email from another mail server. everything's fine till now, 7 march2014 it shown error like:

```
    An unknown error occurred.
Server returned error: "No route to host"
```

and when i check mail, it shown:

```
Error fetching mail. Mail from this account has not been retrieved since Mar 7.  View details
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No route to host" most likely means problems with internet connectivity (link down).

Can you connect the host from your computer to double check it?

Less likely options include e.g. firewalling out google to stop it fetching users' email.